# C# Thread.Start life cycle

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a question about the lifecycle of a thread when i use Thread.Start, for example if a do a foreach loop like this one:

```
foreach(var item in MyList)
{
  var t = new Thread(ProcessRequest);
  t.Start(item);
}

private void ProcessRequest(ListItem item)
{
   //do something
}
```

In this case it will exists N Threads, so what is the lifecycle of all these?

I will appreciate your explanation

Answer (score 1):

Each thread exists until it's ProcessRequest is finished. Once the method returns the thread is returned to the threadpool to be used again.

Even though you are not maintaining a reference to the thread object it's referenced by the framework and the OS so it won't get freed up until the thread is finished running at a minimum.

Comment: +1, except the thread pool part. It won't be used in the sample code provided in the question